# Setting only two rows next to each other in a flexbox of four rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to place .itemtwo and .itemthree next to each other like you see here with boxes "aside 1" and "aside 2":

[placing rows side by side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sVZf.png)

This is my HTML:

```
`<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="itemone">test one</div>
  <div class="itemtwo">test two</div>
  <div class="itemthree">test three</div>
  <div class="itemfour">test four</div>
</div>`
```

This is my CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper > div {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.itemtwo,
.itemthree {
  flex: 1 1 auto;  
  color: red;
}
```

The interesting thing is that when I change the second declaration block `.wrapper > div` to `.wrapper > *` I get my desired effect. I don't understand why my `.wrapper > div` is not working.

Comment: You can learn about specificity at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity In particular * does nothing to specificity but div will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are coming up against specificity.

.wrapper > div has higher specificity than .itemtwo and .itemthree

However .wrapper > * has lower specificity than .itemtwo and .itemthree

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for a description of how specificity is calculated.

In your case * actually has no effect on specificity but the div does.

Here's a way of getting what you want using your code without recourse to using !important. This snippet adds a .wrapper to the .itemtwo and .itemthree to increase the specificity.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.wrapper .itemtwo,
.wrapper .itemthree {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="itemone">test one</div>
  <div class="itemtwo">test two</div>
  <div class="itemthree">test three</div>
  <div class="itemfour">test four</div>
</div>`
```

Comment: Wow, that's what it is. Thanks for the help! I was under the wrong assumption that you add in specificity with each class you add in a list separated by commas. I figured the more classes I had in a group list with commas like above (.itemtwo, .itemthree), I would count them as two class selectors versus the .wrapper > div (class and type). Now I know that in a group of classes separated with commas, the specificity is still considered the same as having one class.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this has something to do with the specificity of the selector. Targeting a tag should have higher priority than the class itself, and using the universal selector '*' will have the lowest priority.

What you could do if you still choose to go down this method is to use the !important exception to force the styling on .itemtwo and .itemthree, which I would not recommend! You can read more about it at this link [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:~:text=Inline%20styles%20added%20to%20an,as%20having%20the%20highest%20specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#:%7E:text=Inline%20styles%20added%20to%20an,as%20having%20the%20highest%20specificity).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.wrapper > div  {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.itemtwo,
.itemthree {
  flex: 1 1 auto !important;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="itemone">test one</div>
  <div class="itemtwo">test two</div>
  <div class="itemthree">test three</div>
  <div class="itemfour">test four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I think I understand more than before, but what I don't seem to get is the grouping of selectors like ".itemtwo, .itemthree". Wouldn't having two classes have precedence over ".wrapper> div", which is just 1 class and 1 element for a lower specificity value?

Comment: There is a method for calculating the specificity, if you really want to go into it, but that’s not determined by the number of classes. All classes will have the same specificity no matter how many you chain together.